# Restrict API endpoint for only one user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a project that require API that does not exist yet (I thought I would never be in this situation... :D) - so I have decided to build my own.

I'm using MongoDB as a database, Node.js, Express.js as backend framework,and Mongoose as ODM tool.

It's very simple API, all I need is 3 get routes:

```
GET example/random-item
GET example/all-items
GET example/some-items/:limit/:skip?
```

And one more thing that I need is a way to post new items to the API:

```
POST example/add-item
```

How can I make sure, that I will be the only one, who can access this route?

I want to be te only person that fan maintain the API, users can only GET data, they cannot POST data.

How does it work in a real word, when someome is maintaining some bigger API with more routes and more data?

Kind regards,
Bartek

Comment: Use [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to authorise the routes.

Comment: Ok, but how do I confirm that me is me?

Comment: read [this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/28/nodejs-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api) article for role based authorisation